# Linking to an unregistered page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, hyperlink

I'm relatively new to wordpress and there is one thing I can't figure out by myself.
I have a number of hardcoded php pages containing tables with several rows of data that I want to link from a registered page in my site.

To make it more clear: Let's say I have a page named Chapters and there I have a list of years. From now on, the content added will be dynamic with custom fields, etc. But for past years, that content is already hardcoded into a static page. So for example, I want to link to `chapters-2012.php`

I know creating page templates for these files and registering them as new pages would do the trick, but I don't want to do it since there are too many files and it would bloat the admin menu, among other things. Also the data in these pages won't be modified so there is no need for them to be editable.
Uploading the pages to my server outside the wp directory and getting the url from there wouldn't be helpful either because it wouldn't get my wp header and footer.

I've tried using php bloginfo to get to the directory where i put the files like I would use with a stylesheet and image or a script but I didn't get it work.

I hope my question is clear for you to understand, looking forward to your answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a php page into your theme folder and open it using the full filepath. If `http://example.com/` usually opens your Wordpress homepage, that would be `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/yourfile1.php`

Comment: I tried your solution and it indeed recognized the page but got a a php error regarding the header. Although I don't know if it is good practice to have the entire directory displayed in the URL. Thanks for your answer, I will keep trying.